# Null pointer when calling @SessionScoped from @RequestScoped

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have a `@RequestScoped` bean that calls a method from a `@SessionScoped` one. Inside the last one, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when I try to get a `java.util.logging.Logger`. This doesn't happens if I call the same method from the `@SessionScoped` directly, not from the other bean...can somebody tell me why is this happening??

The `@RequestScoped` bean:

```
    @RequestScoped
    public class IndexBean {
        @Inject
        private Auth auth;
        public void redirect() throws IOException {
            auth.logout();
        }
    }
```

And the `@SessionScoped` one:

```
@SessionScoped
public class Auth implements Serializable {
    public void logout() {
        Logger.getLogger(Auth.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO,"Logout");
    }
}
```

The exception arises when I call the `redirect()` method.

Comment: Always add the exception stack too.

Comment: give stacktrace of the error